# How to use ArcGIS in JavaFX?

Tags: arcgis-runtime-sdk-java, javafx

Can anyone help me use ArcGIS in [JavaFX](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/overview/javafx-overview-2158620.html).

I have a sample code but it's in swing application.

[Sample code for creating a map](https://developers.arcgis.com/java/sample-code/basic-map/)

I would like to use it in JavaFX.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

See [here](https://developers.arcgis.com/java/guide/get-started-with-javafx-beta-.htm) for an example provided by ArcGIS using JavaFX. There is a class in the ArcGIS SDK called `FXMap`that is used.

Answer (score -4):

Try Using SwingNode , there you can add jcomponent in swingnode as .setcontent(Jcomponet component).